# How do I list the data using mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Recently I have a problem with mongoose. I wanted to get the data of a guild (discord)  and list it in my message. But idk how to get the data from mongodb in typescript. (Note: There is some data is optional so sometimes got some data added or is null like role, msg_num etc)

[image: Image Link]

Comment: You write a `find` query on the collection, then apply _filters_ and/or _projection_ to restrict the data and/or fields you need in your application.

Comment: I used `findOne` that and I got the data. (I am using TypeScript). But now I need to slice the data which is the `_id: ObjectId(...)` and `__v: 0`. But it popped up a err. It said need to use where() before using slice()

Comment: For someone to help, do include what code you had tried and the exact error you are getting in your question post (you can edit your post). Look into Also, refer Mongoose documentation for correct syntax usage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an interface for your guild schema? If you do, you should probably try using mongoose queries and construct a `Collection<string, GuildSchema>` (string - guild ID, GuildSchema - your guild schema's interface).

You can look through [this documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) of mongoose queries, which contains a lot of examples. I suggest you using the [`Model.find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method,which returns a list of objects.